# Cell wise concatenation of python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have multiple arrays of equal size, and I want to concatenate the values in each cell to produce an output array of the same size, but where each element is a list. How can I do this?

Example.

```
Input:
a = [[1,2],
     [3,4]]
b = [[5,6],
     [7,8]]

Desired output:
c = [[[1,5],[2,6]],
     [[3,7],[4,8]]]
```

How can I achieve this? My arrays are actually NumPy arrays, if that helps.

### Followup Question: Concatenate Iteratively

The first answer suggests using np.dstack,  which works for the above example.

How do I do the concatenation in an iterative fashion? After obtaining

```
c = [[[1,5],[2,6]],
     [[3,7],[4,8]]]
```

if I have

```
d = [[9,10],
     [11,12]]
```

I want to "concatenate" c and d to obtain

```
e = [[[1,5,9],[2,6,10]],
     [[3,7,11],[4,8,12]]]
```

Comment: `np.dstack((a, b, d))` or `np.dstack((c, d))` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy-dstack).

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> b
array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
>>> np.dstack((a,b))
array([[[1, 5],
        [2, 6]],

       [[3, 7],
        [4, 8]]])
```

See `help(np.dstack)` for more information and examples

```
>>> help(np.dstack)
Help on function dstack in module numpy:

dstack(tup)
    Stack arrays in sequence depth wise (along third axis).

    This is equivalent to concatenation along the third axis after 2-D arrays
    of shape `(M,N)` have been reshaped to `(M,N,1)` and 1-D arrays of shape
    `(N,)` have been reshaped to `(1,N,1)`. Rebuilds arrays divided by
    `dsplit`.

    This function makes most sense for arrays with up to 3 dimensions. For
    instance, for pixel-data with a height (first axis), width (second axis),
    and r/g/b channels (third axis). The functions `concatenate`, `stack` and
    `block` provide more general stacking and concatenation operations.

    Parameters
    ----------
    tup : sequence of arrays
        The arrays must have the same shape along all but the third axis.
        1-D or 2-D arrays must have the same shape.

    Returns
    -------
    stacked : ndarray
        The array formed by stacking the given arrays, will be at least 3-D.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> a = np.array((1,2,3))
    >>> b = np.array((2,3,4))
    >>> np.dstack((a,b))
    array([[[1, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [3, 4]]])

    >>> a = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
    >>> b = np.array([[2],[3],[4]])
    >>> np.dstack((a,b))
    array([[[1, 2]],
           [[2, 3]],
           [[3, 4]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, in other answers/comments `np.dstack` would be the right way to stack them.

However, if you want to iteratively add items (PART 2 of your question), you can simply modify the list of stacks that you want to `np.dstack` since it's only **referencing the elements of this original list**.

If this final object needs to be the same after each iteration, then you can simply overwrite the object with the next iteration's output.

```
inp = [a,b,d,a,b,d]
l = []

for i in inp:
    l.append(i)
    print(np.dstack(l))
    print('--------')
```

```
    
[[[1]
  [2]]

 [[3]
  [4]]]
-------
[[[1 5]
  [2 6]]

 [[3 7]
  [4 8]]]
-------
[[[ 1  5  9]
  [ 2  6 10]]

 [[ 3  7 11]
  [ 4  8 12]]]
-------
[[[ 1  5  9  1]
  [ 2  6 10  2]]

 [[ 3  7 11  3]
  [ 4  8 12  4]]]
-------
[[[ 1  5  9  1  5]
  [ 2  6 10  2  6]]

 [[ 3  7 11  3  7]
  [ 4  8 12  4  8]]]
-------
[[[ 1  5  9  1  5  9]
  [ 2  6 10  2  6 10]]

 [[ 3  7 11  3  7 11]
  [ 4  8 12  4  8 12]]]
-------
```